Retraining of OpenAI fine tuned model : GPT 3.5 turbo
A hybrid approach, utilising system prompt messages. I tried to retrained the fine tuned GPT 3.5 turbo model with Hybrid data preparation strategy.

Initially, I fine-tuned a base model (gpt-3.5-turbo-1106) on Set 1 data, consisting of 4 labels with 45 records each, totalling 180 records.

Subsequently, I conducted further fine-tuning ( i.e. Retraining) on this initial model.
For data preparation, I adopted a hybrid approach alongside system prompt messages. I selected 40 records from Set 1 data (4 labels * 10 records each = 40) and incorporated 180 records from Set 2 New Data (4 new labels * 45 records each = 180), resulting in a New Set Data of 220 records encompassing 8 labels.


The accuracy results are as follows:
Training 1 Accuracy (Initial Fine tuning model): 85%
Training 2 Accuracy (Retraining above model) : Overall 68% (including Set 1 and Set 2 test data)
Set 1: 65%
Set 2: 75%
But my concern is, this retraining will be Iterative in our case.
when I increase the number of labels around 10 and Fine tuned that model and again retrain that model on new set of labels, then Accuracy dropped by 20% for Set 1 Data.
Question :
Instead of this Hybrid data approach, can we store / retain the weights of first trained gpt-3.5-turbo-1106 model and can retrained on only Set 2 data, Instead of passing Set 1 and Set 2 data for retraining? Is there any way to retain / save those weights ?
Retraining will be Iterative in our case.
